# JavaMail: How to solve SocketException?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, socketexception

I am using the following code to send emails from a Java application. On my computer it works fine, on second computer too, but on another computer (in the same network) it doesn't, although we're using the same connection settings.

```
public void connect() throws MessagingException
{
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator(){ 
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(smtpUser, smtpPassword);
        }
    };
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", this.smtpServer);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true); 

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

    store = session.getStore(this.protocol);
    store.connect(this.mailboxServer, this.user, this.password);  //<-- exception is thrown here

}
```

This is the exception I get:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: connect failed; 
nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:161)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at com.myapp.MailboxConnection.connect(MailboxConnection.java:66)
caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

What could be the reason that it doesn't work on one computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by uninstalling Norton AntiVirus

Answer (score 0):

You should check which port is used, maybe it is an allowed port on your machine, but not on the other.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I also tried deactivating the firewall, but still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i think this may be a network problem or may be a permission problem(change your user privilege as administrator)

check whether your system would be able to connect to the mail server

> ping mailservername/mailserverip eg: ping www.gmail.com/192.168.1.98

Comment: ping works fine. However, using Wireshark I noticed no packages other than the ICMP ping packets are sent to the smtp server, although the firewall (Norton 360) is deactivated and the user has administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code running in an application server with a security manager enabled?  Your application may not have been given permission by the Java runtime to connect to that host.

Comment: Don't know about that securtiy manager, but the application is started like this: `java.exe -jar myapp.jar`. I've tried running the application as administrator too.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't look like a security manager issue.  It looks like something in the operating system on that machine is preventing your application from connecting to that host.  Try the tips in the JavaMail FAQ for debugging connection problems.